# save some data [into the database] every few seconds using Ajax

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, ajax

I have a page where i have to save some data [into the database] every few seconds.This is similar to how gmail or stackoverflow saves a draft every few seconds. I am using jQuery Ajax to achieve this. Following is my Ajax call :

**Question:** Is this the correct way to do this? I am not comfortable with opening and closing the connection every few seconds.

```
function ShowHtml() {
 var SaveStoryForEditing = '<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~")%>Webservices/WebService.asmx/SaveStoryForEditing';

            $('#savedata').html($('#InPlaceEdit').html());
            $("#InPlaceEdit").find("textarea").each(function (idx) {
                $("#savedata").find("textarea").eq(idx).text($(this).val());
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: SaveStoryForEditing,
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                data: "{'StoryEditId':" + $('#hfStoryEditID').val() + ",'AccountId':" + $('#hfAccID').val() + ",'StoryHtml':'" + $('#savedata').html() + "'}", // Page parameter to make sure we load new data
                success: function (data) {
                    var myObject = eval('(' + data.d + ')');

                    $('#InPlaceEdit').effect("highlight", { color: "#ff0000" }, 1000);
                    $('#savedata').html('');
                    AutoSave();

                },
                error: function (result) {
                    AutoSave();
                    alert(JSON.stringify(result));
                }
            });

        };


        function AutoSave() {
            setTimeout("ShowHtml()", 30000);
        };
```

This is the function i am calling from the webservice:

```
Public Shared Function SaveStoryForEditing(ByVal StoryEditId As Integer, ByVal AccountId As Integer, ByVal StoryHtml As String) As Object

        Dim db As SqlDatabase = Connection.Connection
        Dim scalar As Object
        Dim cmdIf As SqlCommand = CType(db.GetSqlStringCommand("UPDATE StoryEdit SET    StoryHtml=@StoryHtml WHERE AccountID=@AccountID AND StoryEditID=@StoryEditID"), SqlCommand)
        db.AddInParameter(cmdIf, "AccountID", DbType.Int32, AccountId)
        db.AddInParameter(cmdIf, "StoryEditID", DbType.Int32, StoryEditId)
        db.AddInParameter(cmdIf, "StoryHtml", DbType.String, StoryHtml)
        scalar = db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmdIf)
        Return scalar


    End Function
```

This is my connection object class:

```
Imports Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Connection
    Public Shared Function Connection() As SqlDatabase
        Dim db As SqlDatabase = New SqlDatabase(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TripNestConStr").ConnectionString)
        Return db
    End Function


    End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is not a good way to go. You're creating (probably) unnecessary traffic. If you really need such functionality, I'd at least consider some kind of mechanism that will track changes and execute ONLY if something has changed after the last server call. You don't really need to send a request to the server and access the database, if the data haven't changed.

Just some idea for you to consider, it all depends on your specific situation and needs.

Comment: You are correct,actually i build this form dynamically and finding it really difficult to track changes. On a different context, is there any way i can further optimize my functions?

Comment: @Monodeep, so your checking mechanism has to be dynamic as well.. :) I know it's not easy, but... If you're looking for code optimizations, I'd suggest you to look at CodeReview (sister site), people there can offer valuable insights. I'm afraid I'm not that good with VB.NET to offer any serious advice about your code, for instance I can't understand why in VB you don't open/close your connection :)) (or at least I can't see this mechanism in your example)

Comment: Thanks for your time :) I am opening/closing my connection in a different function which is not here.

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking why don't use the hidden field kind of flag to check if the value is updated or not. On keypressup of the textarea you can set the hidden value as true. In the autoSave method check the value of the hidden field , if it is true then only go back to server. Once you picked the value update it back to false again . So that it will help you to save some time overload . Another way is rather than saving true false , you can also save the time stamp of change and have a global variable in javascript which will tell the last time you have updated in the database. If the global value is in past compare to current update in  the hidden field , you need to sync.

Comment: Thanks, this is what the other answer also suggests. I am going to try to implement this.Will update you soon.